# Drop Down - Submenu menu Disappear while hover

Tags: html, css

Everything is fine except Submenu while hover... it disappears on hover. I am sure there is some issue in hover. i.e.

```
.dropdown-content a:hover + .dropdown-submenu {
   display: block;
}
```

```css
.icon-cadet-left {
  float: right;
}
.dropbtn {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #338d99;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-family: 'Play';
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: block;

}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
    position: absolute;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin:0px; 
}
.dropdown-content a {
  width: 300px;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Play';
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid #333;
  border-radius: 5%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  
}
.dropdown-submenu {
  display: none;
  margin:0px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: 100%;
  top: 0px;
 }

.dropdown-submenu a {
  width: 300px;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Play';
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid #333;
  border-radius: 5%;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color:#909090;
}
.dropdown-submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
 .dropdown-content a:hover + .dropdown-submenu {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #29727c;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing-button">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Logo Design</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content animated bounce">
                  <a href="#">Logo & Identity<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
                      <div class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#">Logo Design</a>
                        <a href="#">Business Cards</a>
                        <a href="#">Sationary</a>
                        <a href="#">Holiday Doodles</a>
                      </div>
                  <a href="#">Business & Advertising<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
                      <div class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a>Sample 01</a>
                        <a>Sample 02</a>
                        <a>Sample 03</a>
                        <a>Sample 04</a>
                      </div>
                  <a href="#">Website & Digitals<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
                      <div class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a>Option 01</a>
                        <a>Option 02</a>
                        <a>Option 03</a>
                        <a>Option 04</a>
                      </div>
                  <a href="#">Textile Designing<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
                      <div class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a>Sample 01</a>
                        <a>Sample 02</a>
                        <a>Sample 03</a>
                        <a>Sample 04</a>
                      </div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to add `.dropdown-submenu:hover` to your `display: block;` rule. Without, the submenu disappears because you hover no longer over the `a` tag.

```css
.icon-cadet-left {
  float: right;
}
.dropbtn {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #338d99;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-family: 'Play';
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  width: 300px;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Play';
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid #333;
  border-radius: 5%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
  display: none;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: 100%;
  top: 0px;
}
.dropdown-submenu a {
  width: 300px;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Play';
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid #333;
  border-radius: 5%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: #909090;
}
.dropdown-submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover + .dropdown-submenu,
.dropdown-submenu:hover {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #29727c;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing-button">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Logo Design</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content animated bounce">
      <a href="#">Logo & Identity<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
      <div class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="#">Logo Design</a>
        <a href="#">Business Cards</a>
        <a href="#">Sationary</a>
        <a href="#">Holiday Doodles</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#">Business & Advertising<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
      <div class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a>Sample 01</a>
        <a>Sample 02</a>
        <a>Sample 03</a>
        <a>Sample 04</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#">Website & Digitals<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
      <div class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a>Option 01</a>
        <a>Option 02</a>
        <a>Option 03</a>
        <a>Option 04</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#">Textile Designing<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
      <div class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a>Sample 01</a>
        <a>Sample 02</a>
        <a>Sample 03</a>
        <a>Sample 04</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
.dropdown-content:hover .dropdown-submenu {
```

Instead of

```
.dropdown-content a:hover + .dropdown-submenu {
```

The reason for that is once you move the mouse to hover the `.dropdown-submenu` the `a` node is not hovered anymore, so the `.dropdown-submenu` is not `blocked`.

Here is a working version:

```css
.icon-cadet-left {
  float: right;
}
.dropbtn {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #338d99;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-family: 'Play';
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: block;

}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
    position: absolute;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin:0px; 
}
.dropdown-content a {
  width: 300px;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Play';
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid #333;
  border-radius: 5%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  
}
.dropdown-submenu {
  display: none;
  margin:0px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: 100%;
  top: 0px;
 }

.dropdown-submenu a {
  width: 300px;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Play';
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid #333;
  border-radius: 5%;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color:#909090;
}
.dropdown-submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
 .dropdown-content:hover .dropdown-submenu {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #29727c;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing-button">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Logo Design</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content animated bounce">
                  <a href="#">Logo & Identity<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
                      <div class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#">Logo Design</a>
                        <a href="#">Business Cards</a>
                        <a href="#">Sationary</a>
                        <a href="#">Holiday Doodles</a>
                      </div>
                  <a href="#">Business & Advertising<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
                      <div class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a>Sample 01</a>
                        <a>Sample 02</a>
                        <a>Sample 03</a>
                        <a>Sample 04</a>
                      </div>
                  <a href="#">Website & Digitals<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
                      <div class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a>Option 01</a>
                        <a>Option 02</a>
                        <a>Option 03</a>
                        <a>Option 04</a>
                      </div>
                  <a href="#">Textile Designing<i class="fa fa-caret-right icon-cadet-left"></i></a>
                      <div class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a>Sample 01</a>
                        <a>Sample 02</a>
                        <a>Sample 03</a>
                        <a>Sample 04</a>
                      </div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```